# Is there a way to use the Case function with nvarchar data type when comparing two columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to retrieve values that fulfills a case condition , the condition is

- Case when tr.value < tr.PanicMin then return tr.value
- Case when tr.value > tr.PanicMax  then return tr.value

but i get an error saying 'Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric' since the values in the three columns (tr.panicMin,tr.PanicMax,Tr.value) are not numerical , 
the original query used before adding the case function is:

```
SELECT SP.Specialisation, TSP.SpecimenName,T.Name as Test_Name,TR.Value,TR.PanicMin ,tr.PanicMax , PA.RegCode AS UHID, TT.DoneAt AS COL_DATE, TT1.DoneAt AS ACK_DATE, TT2.DoneAt AS VER_DATE, TT2.DoneBy,
(CAST((DATEDIFF(minute, TT1.DoneAt, TT2.DoneAt))/60 AS VARCHAR)+' H:'                                 
+ CAST((DATEDIFF(minute,TT1.DoneAt,TT2.DoneAt))%60 AS VARCHAR)+' M') AS TAT,
(CASE WHEN TOI.TestID IN (2160, 2878, 956, 1000, 1002, 932, 934) AND ((DATEDIFF(minute, TT1.DoneAt, TT2.DoneAt)) > 60) THEN 'WITHOUT TAT'
WHEN TOI.TestID IN (991, 941, 942, 943, 2396) AND ((DATEDIFF(minute, TT1.DoneAt, TT2.DoneAt)) > 15) THEN 'WITHOUT TAT'
WHEN TT2.DoneAt IS NULL THEN NULL
ELSE 'WITHIN TAT' END) AS TAT_STAT 
FROM v_dbNxGtestorderitems TOI
INNER JOIN V_TestSpecimen TSP ON TSP.TestID = TOI.TestID
INNER JOIN v_dbNxgtestorders TSO ON TSO.TestOrderID = TOI.TestOrderID AND TSO.OrderTypeID = 15
INNER JOIN v_dbSpecializations SP ON SP.SpecialiseID = TOI.SpecialiseID
INNER JOIN v_dbPatientAdmissions PA ON PA.AdmissionID = TOI.AdmissionID
  join v_dbtestresults tr on tr.TestOrderID=TOI.TestOrderID
  join v_Tests t on t.TestId=tr.TestID
  join v_dbTestComponents tc on tc.TestID=tr.TestID
  join v_dbComponents c on c.ComponentID=tr.ComponentID
CROSS apply   (select top 1  TestOrderID, TestOrderItemID, DoneAt  from  v_dbtesttasks
where TestOrderID=toi.TestOrderID and    TestOrderItemID=toi.TestOrderItemID and taskStatusid=3
Order  by DoneAt desc  )  tt
CROSS apply   (select top 1  TestOrderID, TestOrderItemID, DoneAt  from  v_dbtesttasks
where TestOrderID=toi.TestOrderID and    TestOrderItemID=toi.TestOrderItemID and taskStatusid=4
Order  by DoneAt desc  )  tt1
outer  apply   (select top 1  TestOrderID, TestOrderItemID, DoneAt, SD.Name AS DoneBy from  v_dbtesttasks TTS
INNER JOIN v_dbSecurityIds SD ON SD.SID = TTS.DoneBy
where TestOrderID=toi.TestOrderID and    TestOrderItemID=toi.TestOrderItemID and taskStatusid=8
order  by DoneAt desc  )  tt2
WHERE TOI.TestID in (932, 934, 941, 942, 943, 991, 1000, 1002, 2396, 2878, 2160) AND TSO.OrderDate > '2019-01-01' AND TSO.OrderDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2019-01-10')
```

and the query output is 
[image]

Comment: why don't you use the CAST function?

Comment: the best solution is not to store numerical data in a (n)varchar column

Comment: I used the cast function to numeric and nvarchar and still getting the same error

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Please always include this information.

Comment: You could always try ISNUMERIC() to see what values are not numeric in those columns.  Once you know what the problem values are you can address them or why they're being put in there in the first place.

Comment: It's SQL Server 2012 , the issue was solved by using the float data type , i will try not to forget to include which version I'm using next time thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012 and above, you can use:

```
CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(float, tr.value) < TRY_CONVERT(float, tr.PanicMin)
       OR TRY_CONVERT(float, tr.value) > TRY_CONVERT(float, tr.PanicMax)
  THEN tr.value END
```

On older versions one approach requires you to rely on a kind of flaky function and nested `CASE` expressions:

```
CASE 
  WHEN ISNUMERIC(tr.PanicMin) = 1 
   AND ISNUMERIC(tr.PanicMax) = 1
   AND ISNUMERIC(tr.value) = 1 
  THEN 
    CASE 
      WHEN CONVERT(float, tr.value) < CONVERT(float, tr.PanicMan)
           OR CONVERT(float, tr.value) > CONVERT(floar, tr.PanixMax)
      THEN tr.value
    END
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try convert  for trasfrom you string  with a numeric content in a float

```
 convert(float,'9.0')
```

in your case

```
convert(float, tr.PanicMin)
```